# Self added secondary screen / extended desktop off-screen

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, extended-desktop

One morning I turn on the PC but there was no video signal coming out from my pc.
I reboot my pc and again I could see my desktop: Aero Peek Win7's theme has been set with no transparency (I didn't do that) and there seems to be some sort of an extended screen that I did not set up.
I have used dual extended screen before but I do not have it anymore. Also it seems different:

I cannot directly see the second screen because I'm not using a secondary (physical) screen. It's on the left of my main desktop, it's smaller and seems to be on portrait mode.
I realized it was there when I couldn't open my windows bar (placed on the left of the screen and it auto hides) on mouse hover and there was no "border" on the left of my screen so dragging a window to the left make it completely disappear if small enough.

It is hard to explain it so fortunately if I take a screenshot it shows actually all of what I should see.

[image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzU25vdAON7SMkthR3RMSE5NU3M]

From the screenshot you can see my current browser in full screen on a `BenQ GL2450H 1920x1080`, then there's another "peice" of desktop on the left of it with a black bar under it (if you don't know, that should be "void"/empty desktop/no desktop).

I have no idea why that is here.
I just updated my video card driver but nothing happened.

I don't know if it could be related to the GPU (`NVidia GeForce GTX 750Ti 2Gb`) since it gave me some minor problems in the past (as I was saying at the beginning) like not sending the signal correctly but I usually fixed this by rebooting my pc.

(This next part could be both off-topic or useful)
*Just yesterday I had to reboot several times until I got video signal only from my internal graphic card. I realized after that I forgot to switch port for my VGA video cable (my pc has to VGA outputs and I was trying to switch port checking if that was the problem).
Still, before rebooting another several times I wasn't getting any video signal.*

In conclusion it's not a major problem but it's annoying.
Ask me whatever is useful about my software or hardware specs in case I forgot to mention them.

```
OS: Windows 7 64bit
GPU: NVidia GeForce GTX 750Ti 2Gb
Screen: BenQ GL2450H
```

**EDIT 1**:
I don't know if it could help but I used a tool to get mouse coordinates:
the "added" section of the screen has "768x1024" resolution (X coordinate go negative when I place my curson at the top left corner - outside of the monitor - "x:-768,y:0")

**EDIT 2**:
My windows bar moved entirely at that other screen and I can't get it back in the real screen even if I place it on the right site (I usually use it on the left).
Whichever side I chose it stays in the small screen.
Now it's starting to be difficult to use my pc: can anybody help me?
This windows thing just happened when I was trying different things in order to fix something: I disabled completely all the graphical preferences and then set them on again.
Areo Peek still isn't working, my desktop size is still messed up and I noticed different graphical errors while playing some games. At this point I suspect it must be my GPU that is causing all this.
I have no idea how (I don't remember if I mentioned before but I even updated my gpu drivers) but it might make sense since Aero is related with graphics.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue today. The below worked for me.

1. On your desktop, right click and select 'screen resolution'.
2. In your display settings, select the appropriate 'resolution' of your laptop or desktop monitor.

You should now be able to see the normal screen size. Hope this helps !

Comment: It's weird because my resolution settings are just fine (1920x1080): even if I lower it nothing happens. Basically it's like I got some sort of a 2688x1080 (I got this value thanks to Photoshop).